# Illustrator Logo File Changes Colors When Imported Into Adobe Products

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Sorry non-graphic designer here (EE / firmware coder!).  I've got the weirdest thing, I don't know what's going on.

I have an illustrator logo file that has the correct color (sample here):

[image]

I can get Illustrator to export all kinds of the correct color files from Illustrator.

But when I import one of those files, I always get a result like the below (both in Photoshop and InDesign:

[image]

What is going with the colors in the file?  I can take a 2mb JPEG of the logo, but when I import it the color shifts.

What am I missing here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Illustrator file is in **RGB** color mode

- Go to **Menu File** > **Document Color Mode** and chose the right one:

[image: RGB]

The InDesign file is in **CMYK** color mode

- Go to **Menu Edit** > **Transparency Blend Space** and chose the right one:

[image: CMYK]

Comment: So that is so obvious.  I don't know why my Indesign guy didn't catch this when I asked him.  Thanks.  Let me try to adjust the color in CMYK in Illustrator.

Comment: Okay, so here is the deal.  Is it possible CMYK can't quite replicate the RGB color?  Because I convert the RGB values to CMYK and I end up with the blue that does not match.  Should I just eyeball a blue that is close, is there a better way to get this color match from RGB to CMYK?  The target color is: #007AFF

Comment: – Should I just eyeball a blue that is close...– Where's the Graphic Designer of this logo??? This is the professional who has to tell you which is the CMYK equivalent color.

Comment: Well, you get what you get for $30 logo design. ;)

Comment: @Leroy105 I'm sure the CMYK color is included in this price.

Comment: @Leroy105 the original sRGB color isn't printable in the CMYK printing system that your software is configured to emulate to show the proof colors. The ability to do it has lifted Adobe's software to the position it now has. There's plenty of good drawing software which has not a slightest idea of what happens when the image is going to be printed in some CMYK printing process.